# How to import data from Google sheets to Slides

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a button in google sheets that run a script every time it is triggered. The script should first create a new copy of the template and then using that google sheet replace all placeholder text in that presentation with data from sheets. I am not sure why the code is not working as of now.

```
// The following creates the UI button in sheets (This works)
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Create Report')
  .addItem('Create Report', 'executeAll')
  .addToUi();
}

function executeAll (){
  var reportTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Presentation ID goes Here');
  var copiedTemplate = reportTemplate.makeCopy('New Report', DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID Goes here"));
  var skeleton = SlidesApp.openById(copiedTemplate.getId());
  var slides = skeleton.getSlides();
  return slide1();


  function slide1 (){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('App Script Input Sheet');
    var data = sheet.getRange('E1:F26').getValues;
    var slide1 = slides[0];
    var newslide1 = slide1.duplicate();
    var shapes = (newslide1.getShapes());
      shapes.forEach(function(shape){
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Date}}',data[2]);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Title}}',data[3]);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Value 1}}',data[4]);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Value 2}}',data[5]);
        //there are more to be replaced. will add once code works. 
       

      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I am not sure why the code is not working as of now.` and your detailed goal?

Comment: Hey So, it creates the new presentation but it does not fill the placeholders @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. And, I apologize for my late reply. When I saw your script, it is required to modify `var data = sheet.getRange('E1:F26').getValues;` to `var data = sheet.getRange('E1:F26').getValues();`. In this case, an error occurs. But from `Hey So, it creates the new presentation but it does not fill the placeholders` and your question, you don't mention the error. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. So can you confirm your showing script again?